# Sencha Touch 2 RC: show() not working on Ext.Container with card layout

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I've just upgraded from ST 2 Beta 3 to the Release Candidate that came out yesterday. I have a menu bar with buttons, so that when you tap them, a new card will be shown - just like a tabpanel. It worked before the upgrade, but now nothing is shown. It's like the show() method doesn't work any longer. If I look at the source code (inspect element in Chrome) i see that there is a class called x-item-hidden on the div and it has the inline style display: none; ... like this:

```
<div class="x-container x-panel x-item-hidden x-fullscreen" id="ext-panel-1" style="display: none !important; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; ">
```

When I remove "display: none !important;" the content is shown.

Has anyone seen this problem and how do i solve it?

---

Edit:

Sorry for not adding code, but didn't know which parts to add. However I've now narrowed the problem a bit down.
In my controller I have:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        calendarPanel: '#idCalendar',
        ...
}
```

Then I call this member function to hide its content:

```
hidePanels : function(){
    this.getCalendarPanel().hide();
    ...
},
```

The this.getCalendarPanel().hide(); hides the panel as it's supposed to, but subsequent calls to this.getCalendarPanel().show(); does not show the panel again as it did in the last versions of ST2.

Comment: Yes, code please. Perhaps the best place to post though is on the Sencha Touch 2 Bugs forum (if you haven't already)- sounds like a regression. http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?92-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Bugs